# After upgrade, conda env no longer sees packages

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I've upgraded conda (to 4.9.0) with the command:

```
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

recommended by conda itself, in "WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. (...)"

After that, another environment no longer sees the packages it had before:

```
conda activate tstb2
conda list
```

produces an empty list. I'm running Anaconda under Windows 10.

Is this behaviour normal? Is there a way to get back my former `tstb2` environment?

**Edit:** I'm adding the cmd output below.

```
(tstb2) C:\Users\ws>conda activate tstb2

(tstb2) C:\Users\ws>conda list -n tstb2
# packages in environment at C:\Users\ws\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tstb2:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel

(tstb2) C:\Users\ws>conda info

     active environment : tstb2
    active env location : C:\Users\ws\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tstb2
            shell level : 2
       user config file : C:\Users\ws\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\ws\.condarc
          conda version : 4.9.0
    conda-build version : 3.18.9
         python version : 3.7.4.final.0
       virtual packages : __win=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : C:\Users\ws\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\ws\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\ws\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\ws\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\ws\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\ws\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\ws\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.9.0 requests/2.24.0 CPython/3.7.4 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17763
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

**Edit 2:** The modules are still visible to `pip`.

Comment: The way I tackled it eventually was to recreate the env based on my project's `setup.py`.

Comment: Thanks for following back up! Yeah, that's really odd behavior. Feel free to post your workaround as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I tackled it eventually was to recreate the env based on my project's `setup.py`. I've no idea where it came from, though.